# Why new PingReply not possible?

Tags: c#, .net

When using the SendPingAsync method of the System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping object, it will throw an exception of PingException when attempting to ping a hostname that does not resolve (i.e. localhostnowhere).

But when catching the exception it isn't possible to new up a PingReply?

```
  PingReply pingReply = null;
  try
  {
    pingReply = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(host, timeout, buffer, options);
  }
  catch (PingException ex)
  {
    pingReply = new PingReply();
    //other pingReply properties set here, like status <> success, etc
  }
  catch (ArgumentNullException) { }
  catch (Exception) { throw; }
```

In looking at the definition of PingReply it does not have a default constructor. It doesn't have any constructors.

```
#region Assembly System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll
#endregion

namespace System.Net.NetworkInformation
{
  //
  // Summary:
  //     Provides information about the status and data resulting from a Overload:System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send
  //     or Overload:System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendAsync operation.
  public class PingReply
  {
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the status of an attempt to send an Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP)
    //     echo request and receive the corresponding ICMP echo reply message.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus value indicating the result of the
    //     request.
    public IPStatus Status { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the address of the host that sends the Internet Control Message Protocol
    //     (ICMP) echo reply.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An System.Net.IPAddress containing the destination for the ICMP echo message.
    public IPAddress Address { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the number of milliseconds taken to send an Internet Control Message Protocol
    //     (ICMP) echo request and receive the corresponding ICMP echo reply message.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An System.Int64 that specifies the round trip time, in milliseconds.
    public long RoundtripTime { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the options used to transmit the reply to an Internet Control Message Protocol
    //     (ICMP) echo request.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions object that contains the Time to
    //     Live (TTL) and the fragmentation directive used for transmitting the reply if
    //     System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply.Status is System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success;
    //     otherwise, null.
    public PingOptions Options { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the buffer of data received in an Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP)
    //     echo reply message.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A System.Byte array containing the data received in an ICMP echo reply message,
    //     or an empty array, if no reply was received.
    public byte[] Buffer { get; }
  }
}
```

How would one go about returning a PingReply for scenarios where the ping was not successful?  How is Ping able to return a new PingReply?

Comment: You answered your own question. That class does not have a public constructor. Create you own model to map the desired members to be exposed.

Comment: When that exception occurs, the method does _not_ return a `PingReply` because there's actually no reply. So, why do you want to return a `PingReply` yourself? If there is some information that you'd like to return, create your own class, add all the properties you desire (including a `PingReply` if needed) and make your method return an instance of that class.

Comment: @ahmed-abdelhameed yep. for some reason my brain was seeing PingReply as the result of the Ping method and not the actual network Ping.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PingReply constructors are defined as internal and

> Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

That's way you cannot call them since your code is not in the same assembly, yet Ping is.
In case SendPingAsync was not performed at all, you will get an exception. If is was performed, you may check pingReply.Status.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a reason to want to create PingReply objects. In my case I had some routines that take PingReply objects as parameters, and I wanted to create unit tests for them. Eventually I found that this can be done using C# reflection.

Before going further, I'll add that it's generally not a good idea to override the author of a class's intentions like this, but for unit testing purposes for a hobbiest like me, I think it's probably OK.

Here's a class I wrote to that will create arbitrary PingReply objects:

```
public static class NewPingReply {
  public static PingReply Create(IPAddress address, PingOptions? options,
    IPStatus ipStatus, long rtt, byte[] buffer) 
  {
    var args = new object?[5] {address, options, ipStatus, rtt, buffer};
    var types = new Type[5] {typeof(IPAddress), typeof(PingOptions), 
      typeof(IPStatus), typeof(long), typeof(byte[])};
    var conInfo = typeof(PingReply)
      .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic, types);
    var newObj = conInfo?.Invoke(args);
    return newObj is PingReply pr ? pr : throw new Exception("failure to create PingReply");
  }
}
```

You'd invoke it as follows, using the parameters you want of course:

```
 PingReply timedOutPingReply = NewPingReply.Create(IPAddress.Parse("10.1.1.1"),
                                    null, IPStatus.TimedOut, 0, Array.Empty<byte>());
```

References:

- https://concurrency.com/blog/june-2019/using-c-reflection-to-succinctly-access-private-members
- https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Ping/System/Net/NetworkInformation/PingReply.cs,ef83696bcda15218
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getconstructor?view=net-7.0#system-type-getconstructor(system-reflection-bindingflags-system-type())

Answer (score 0):

This code can work in unit tests, yet avoids the complexities and other problems associated with Reflection.

```
public interface IPinger
{
    Task<IPStatus> SendPingAsync(IPAddress ipAddress);
}

public class MyPinger : IPinger
{
    readonly Ping _pinger;

    public MyPinger()
    {
        _pinger = new Ping();
    }

    public async Task<IPStatus> SendPingAsync(IPAddress ipAddress)
    {
        var pingReply = await _pinger.SendPingAsync(ipAddress);
        return pingReply.Status;
    }
}
```